# How to fetch only selected column in solr rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I am using rails with solr

I want to search on user and my user table have 12 field my mode is User

name,city,state,image,comment,status,note etc ...

in my user model

```
searchable do
    text :name, :city
end
```

when I do search using

```
@search = User.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
end
@users = @search.results
```

This will return me all field from database but I only wont three field name,city,state how can I get only three field using solr search.
how can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you would do that but anyway you can use `@search.hits` instead of `@search.results` and load whatever you want using ids.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `@search.results`, sunspot loads all matched records from your SQL database.

If you want to avoid hitting your SQL database, you can store the needed fields in Solr. You need to update your searchable definition

```
searchable do
  text :name, stored: true
  text :city, stored: true
end
```

and then reindex your model `User.reindex`. Then you can query your data like

```
@search = User.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@users = @search.hits.each do |hit|
  puts "#{hit.stored(:name)} #{hit.stored(:city)}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Schema

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="city" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="state" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

<field name="copiedfield" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Now all the field from you want to search, set source value of use copyField tag to copy from source field to dest
Example Schema :

```
<copyField source="name" dest="copiedfield"/>
<copyField source="city" dest="copiedfield"/>
<copyField source="state" dest="copiedfield"/>
```

now you can search only by copiedfield

**EDIT**

*you can do another way be searching in every column alone but this way is slow than copyField*